# How to enable two-column view with cventry in ModernCV?

Tags: xetex, lists, moderncv

I currently have a list of cventrys structured like this:

```
\cventry{}{Example 1}{}{}{}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Sample 1
\item Sample 2
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{}{Example 2}{}{}{}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Sample 3
\item Sample 4
\end{itemize}}
```

How would I enable two columns so I could have Example 1 on the left side and Example 2 on the right side?

This is my current header:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}       
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-11mm}
```

What it looks like now. If i added the margin that was provided the entire margin on the left gets removed.
[image: Error]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of abusing the `\cventry` here. Simply do this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{red}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\firstname{Joe}
\familyname{}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \textbf{Example 1}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Sample 1
      \item Sample 2
    \end{itemize}
    \columnbreak 
    \textbf{Example 1}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Sample 3
      \item Sample 4
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this and updated my header above and it is floating into the margin. The result is updated above. How would i justify it right?

Comment: I have pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/KBRHS4WL