# moderncv - two column \cventry within \section

Tags: two-column, moderncv, tabu, tabulary

I'm writing a resume with the `moderncv` package. Due to the lack of space, I want to make one section use two columns, separated by a vertical line.

I've saw those solutions here, using [\cvlistdoubleitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96797/76157) and [multicols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196826/76157). But I'd like to keep the further information provided by `\cventry` (=> I mean, in my case "basic" and "very basic")

### first approach, using tabular

```
<!-- language: lang-latex -->
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \section{headline}
    \begin{tabular}{l@{}|@{\hspace{5mm}}l}
        \cventry{}{C\#}{basic}{}{}{} & \cventry{}{UNIX}{basic}{}{}{} \\
        \cventry{}{vim}{basic}{}{}{} & \cventry{}{\LaTeX}{basic}{}{}{} \\
        \cventry{}{HTML, CSS, PHP}{very basic}{}{}{} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### results in:

```
headline                                             site border
========                                                 :
                                                         :
    C#, basic                             |             U:NIX, basic
    vim, basic                            |             L:aTeX, basic
    HTML, CSS, PHP, very basic            |
```

`@{}` should - as I understood it - eat up all amounts of whitespace between the first column and the separator, but here its just ignored and I don't know why.
=> in that example, I want to move the second column and the separator line to the left and push it a bit together, so that both columns are visible and not cut.

### second approach, using `tabulary`

```
<!-- language: lang-latex -->
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
    \section{headline}
    \begin{tabulary}{1.5\textwidth }{L|L}
        \cventry{}{c\#}{basic}{}{}{} & \cventry{}{UNIX}{basic}{}{}{}    \\
        \vspace{-2cm}                & \vspace{-2cm}                    \\
        \cventry{}{vim}{basic}{}{}{} & \cventry{}{\LaTeX}{basic}{}{}{}  \\
        \vspace{-2cm}                & \vspace{-2cm}                    \\
        \cventry{}{HTML, CSS, PHP}{very basic}{}{}{}                    \\
    \end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

### results in:

```
headline                                                   site border
========                                                      :
                                                              :
    C#, basic                      |       UNIX, basic        :
                                   |                          :
    vim, basic                     |       LaTeX, basic       :
                                   |                          :
    HTML, CSS, PHP, very basic     |                          :
```

the intention of using`\vspace` was to remove the visible white space between the rows, so that its a bit vertically squeezed - unfortunately, `\vspace` isn't recognized and I don't know why.

### third approach, using `tabu`

```
<!-- language: lang-latex -->
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
    \section{headline}
    \tracingtabu=3
    \tabulinesep=-10mm
    \begin{tabu} to 170mm {X[1.5,l] | X[1,l]}
        \cventry{}{C\#}{basic}{}{}{} & \cventry{}{UNIX}{basic}{}{}{} \\
        \cventry{}{vim}{basic}{}{}{} & \cventry{}{\LaTeX}{basic}{}{}{} \\
        \cventry{}{HTML, CSS, PHP}{very basic}{}{}{}
    \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

### results in:

```
headline                                                   site border
========                                                      :
                                                              :
    C#, basic                      |       UNIX, basic        :
                                   |                          :
    vim, basic                     |       LaTeX, basic       :
                                   |                          :
    HTML, CSS, PHP, very basic     |                          :
```

`\tabulinesep=-10mm` should according to the tabu docs specify the minimum amount of whitespace between the rows, which does actually work - but only to "increase", not to "reduce" the whitespace.

`\tracingtabu=3` should help to debug tabu, but the additional values in the log doesn't help me, I don't found anything useful out of it.

**=>** any ideas? I hope, i didn't forget something.

**EDIT:** My result of @Harish Kumar s suggestion is [image: here]

from the log file:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@firstname
                       {}~\@lastname {}
l.13 \begin{document}
```

although it is a exact copy of his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a `minipage` with `multicols`?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\firstname{}
\lastname{}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
    \section{headline}
    \hspace*{\hintscolumnwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
    \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0pt}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \cventry{}{C\#}{basic}{}{}{} \par \cventry{}{UNIX}{basic}{}{}{} \par
        \cventry{}{vim}{basic}{}{}{} \par \cventry{}{\LaTeX}{basic}{}{}{} \par
        \cventry{}{HTML, CSS, PHP}{very basic}{}{}{} \par
    \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Well, i copy pasted your code and receive that: http://vpaste.net/lssvP
It seems, that multicol itself isn't recognized correctly. I'm still debugging.

Comment: (i added a image of that in my original post)

Comment: @toogley Please update your tex distribution.

Comment: i'm using fedora 22 and the default repository. updating shows the newest version is installed and texlive 2015 comes not until fedora 24 :/